# Shell_NotifyIcon: balloon tooltip is shown after 10 seconds delay

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, system-tray, trayicon

My code to show balloon tooltip is:

```
BOOL CTrayIcon::ShowBaloon(LPCTSTR title, LPCTSTR text, HICON hIcon)
{
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;
    if(m_hWnd != NULL)
    {
        NOTIFYICONDATA nfidata = {sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA)};
        nfidata.cbSize = sizeof(nfidata);
        nfidata.hWnd   = m_hWnd;
        nfidata.guidItem = guid;
        nfidata.uFlags = NIF_INFO | NIF_GUID;
        if (hIcon)
        {
            nfidata.hBalloonIcon = hIcon;
            nfidata.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_USER | NIIF_LARGE_ICON;
        }

        StringCchCopy(nfidata.szInfo, ARRAYSIZE(nfidata.szInfo), text);
        StringCchCopy(nfidata.szInfoTitle, ARRAYSIZE(nfidata.szInfoTitle), title);
        bRes = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nfidata);
    }
    return bRes;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the balloon is shown after 10 seconds delay. This only happens when debugger is not connected to the application. If I connect debugger to the app then tooltip is shown immediately. I know that Windows 7 manages balloon tooltips with a different way than previous Win versions. But where can I read more about this? And how can I change this behavior? I need to show tooltip immediately after function call. Or maybe there are any alternatives to Shell_NotifyIcon?

Comment: Are there other notifications already being displayed? The OS can only display 1 at a time, so non-realtime notifications are queued and displayed in order, so there can be a delay.

Comment: No, there are no other notifications.

Answer (score 0):

If it's vital that the notification should be seen immediately, for example notification of a telephone ringing, then you should probably be setting the `NIF_REALTIME` flag.

However, be aware that this also means that the notification won't be displayed at all if for some reason it can't be displayed immediately. The assumption is that if it's a realtime notification, it is only relevant at the time it occurs.

Something like a notification that you've just received an email is not a realtime event.

Comment: I already tried using NIF_REALTIME flag. The tooltip isn't showing at all in this case.

Comment: I guess that makes sense if there is something in your code (or possibly in the OS itself) that is preventing notifications from happening immediately. Have you tried making a very simple application that does nothing but post a notification. That might help determine if it's something else in your application, for example something blocking the UI thread, that is causing the delay.

Comment: I'll try, but as I can see thread is not blocked. Application handles all the UI interactions and works as normal.

Comment: I made a small app and it is completely insane. Sometimes it shows tooltips immediately and sometimes it shows them after 10 seconds. I can not find any explanation to this.

Comment: My phone and laptop both notify me about emails less than a second after I receive them.  No notification should ever have a ten-second delay unless there's something to block it altogether (like a game or user setting).